# Where is the bitcoin wallet file location on android smartphone?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I'm trying to find the bitcoin wallet files on my phone Anyone can help?

Comment: Yes thanks Do I need root to see /data/data/... It isn't visible in file explorer on my phone Would android studio file explorer show the directory and files? If not does that mean I'm gonna have to try to root the phone?

Comment: From the linked answer `This directory is "private" to the app – which means no other app and not even the user can access data in it (without root permissions).` But you should consider that your device uses Android 7 which is pretty old. Using root exploits other apps may be able to access the wallet data.

Comment: Some time ago I wanted to root the phone (Blu) by compiling TWRP myself but I couldn't find BoardConfig.mk: Find the BoardConfig.mk for your device. The BoardConfig.mk is in your devices/manufacturer/codename folder (e.g. devices/lge/hammerhead/BoardConfig.mk). At that time I gave up trying and yielded my time to other priorities I guess I'm back

Comment: TWRP is not required for rooting. Not even unlocked bootloader for older devices. read about [Magisk](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info)

Comment: Requirements
    Unlocked bootloader
    Custom recovery like TWRP

Comment: I couldn't download the apk, it has to be builtand build fails on my system, even with proper path and environment variables set as described Suggested command line options --debug, --info, --scan, --stacktrace all cause an argument error If you wrote it I think it needs fixing

Comment: Mediatek Blu Grand M2

Comment: then the most straightforward way is [mtk-su](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) (no root) or [bootless-root](https://github.com/JunioJsv/mtk-easy-su)

Comment: The most straightforward way to do what

Comment: open adb shell, execute mtk-su, copy /data/data/pkgname bitcoin wallet